Linting Error in a Yaml File: expected the node content, but found '-' (syntax)
I have an existing set of yaml files for which I wrote a basic yaml linting configuration. But, I am always getting an error :

error    syntax error: expected the node content, but found '-' (syntax)

Code syntax:
{{- $chartChart := include "chartName.chart" . -}}
{{- $releaseName := .Release.Name -}}
{{- $releaseService := .Release.Service -}}

I tried removing some rules for braces but didn't work.

your code is not a valid YAML What you have is go template

Okay, even if it is a go template inside yaml, is there a way in yaml configuration to not consider this an error? @rkosegi

No. The problem is that it is not a template inside YAML, but only after processing the template syntax it will be (hopefully) valid YAML. YAML is used in a lot of contexts. You cannot expect from every YAML processor to recognize any existing templating syntax on the planet ;-)
